Spring Security Basic Auth: JSESSIONID cookie from Postman not authorizing subsequent requests (401 error)
In my Spring Security 3.1.0 application, I successfully accessed a secured endpoint using Postman. Authentication with Basic Auth (username and password) was granted, allowing me to view the endpoint and receive a JSESSIONID cookie in the response header.
However, subsequent attempts to access the same endpoint without authentication (No Auth) and with the previously obtained JSESSIONID cookie in the request header fail. I receive a 401 Unauthorized error, even though I'm including the JSESSIONID cookie.
The expected behavior is to grant access to the secured endpoint when the JSESSIONID cookie is provided in the request header, indicating a previously authenticated session.
Please find SecurityConfigration below I am using
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService(PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return new CustomUserDetailService();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration,
                                                       @Autowired UserDetailsService userDetailsService) throws Exception {

        AuthenticationManagerBuilder managerBuilder = new AuthenticationManagerBuilder(Objects::requireNonNull);
        managerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
        return managerBuilder.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAnyRole("ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/teams/**").hasAnyRole("USER"));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests.anyRequest().permitAll());

        http.formLogin(form -> form
                .loginPage("/loginuser")  // Set custom login page URL
                .permitAll()         // Allow access to the login page without authentication
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/home") // Redirect to /home on successful login (optional)
        );

        http.httpBasic();

        http.csrf().disable();
        http.headers(h -> h.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable));
        return (SecurityFilterChain) http.build();
    }
}


Can you add your security configuration? Most likely your security filter chain isn’t configured properly

Hi @kSp I have added securityConfiguration, please check

There's a lot going on in your SecurityConfiguration, you are using configuration methods that will work but that are deprecated or will become deprecated in the near future. I highly suggest you look into the current Spring Security Documentation, this should be the correct documentation for 3.1.0: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/6.0/index.html
Anyway to enable Spring to publish the Session to the WebApplicationContext you need to add the following bean:
@Bean
public HttpSessionEventPublisher httpSessionEventPublisher() {
    return new HttpSessionEventPublisher();
}

